# Produce unique columns for each unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df column that has book categories. For each unique value in this column, I want to create a seperate column.

I have tried `x.explode('A')` and then I `x.unstack(level=-1)`.
It didn't work

```
x=pd.DataFrame({'A':['action,adventure','adventure,biographies',
'biographies,action','adventure,diaries','biographies,diaries',
'diaries,adventure'], 
'B':[1,1,2,3,7,5]})
```

```
    action  adventure   biographies   diaries
0      1           1        NaN         NaN
1     NaN          1         1          NaN
2      2          NaN        2          NaN
3     NaN          3        NaN          3
4     NaN         NaN        7           7
5     NaN          5        NaN          5
```

Comment: Seems like a simple pivot / crosstab have you looked into those?

Comment: can you show your expected output  DataFrame?

Comment: `x.assign(A=x.A.str.split(',')).explode('A').reset_index().pivot_table(index='index', columns='A', values='B')`

Comment: @ansev I have mentioned the expected dataframe below the codeblock

Comment: @user3483203 Awesome! Thanks Chris! It worked. Could you please explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a mix of `pivot`, `explode` and `str.split(',')`
First the `str.split(',')` will generate a list of the strings originall separated by `,`. Afterwards we use `explode()` on that column to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values. Finally by pivoting, we can assign the values of the column we `exploded` as headers for our new dataframe.

This seems to do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
x=pd.DataFrame({'A':['action,adventure','adventure,biographies',
'biographies,action','adventure,diaries','biographies,diaries',
'diaries,adventure'], 
'B':[1,1,2,3,7,5]})
x['A'] = x['A'].str.split(',')
x = x.explode('A')
final_df = x.pivot(columns='A')
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
   B
A action adventure biographies diaries
0    1.0       1.0         NaN     NaN
1    NaN       1.0         1.0     NaN
2    2.0       NaN         2.0     NaN
3    NaN       3.0         NaN     3.0
4    NaN       NaN         7.0     7.0
5    NaN       5.0         NaN     5.0
```